# mysql query in order to get the post ids like twitter homefeed which will show our posts and also our followings post

Tags: mysql, join

I am having 2 tables names posts and follows

the structure of posts table is

> id | uid | text | time

follows table has the userid and the followers user id the structure of follows table is

> uid | followingid

Now I need to write a query in order to get the post ids like twitter homefeed which will show our posts and also our followings post.

```
SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
INNER JOIN follows ON posts.uid = follows.followingid 
AND follows.uid = "'.$currentuser.'" OR posts.uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
```

but this is not working if there is no entry in the follows table.

Comment: You are forcing inner join which will not return any result if any of the records are not exist in FOLLOWS table so the root of the problem is inner join.

Comment: Maybe you should change `following` to `follower` first. :)

Comment: @domanokz better i change it to followid, because both are confusing for me.

Comment: @Vasanth - You mean comments of followers are also in the posts table?

Comment: @domanokz not comments just posts..

Comment: @Vasanth - So, tell me if I'm wrong okay? You want to get posts id of a user, also the follower's posts?

Comment: @domanokz yes exactly.. If I am user, then posts of mine and the persons I follow. (same as twitter)

Comment: @VasanthV let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1349/discussion-between-domanokz-and-vasanth-v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically want to get all posts of the current user and all posts of the user followed by the current user. So here's the code, I use union. First I select all the current user's post, next I select the posts of user followed by the current user.

```
select posts.id
from posts
where posts.uid = "'.$currentuser.'"

union all

select posts.id
from posts
inner join follows
on follows.followingid = posts.uid
where follows.uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
```

Comment: No left join didnt work as it gets all the posts id, irrespective of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing that with a `LEFT JOIN`, like:

```
SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
   LEFT JOIN follows ON posts.uid = follows.followingid 
      AND follows.uid = "'.$currentuser.'" 
WHERE posts.uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
```

Comment: No left join didnt work as it gets all the posts id, irrespective of the condition.

Comment: Try the query now - I put the posts.uid condition in the `WHERE` clause instead of `ON` one

Comment: I tried it now. same problem, it lists all the posts irrespective of the condition.